# Does try/finally ignore exceptions?

Tags: exception, finally

I have a situation where I want certain code to be executed no matter what happens, but I need exceptions to also be passed on up the stack to be handled later. Is the following:

```
try
{
  // code
}
finally
{
  // code that must run
}
```

going to just ignore any exceptions, or will it pass them on up?  My testing seems to show that they still get passed on up, but I want to be sure I'm not crazy.

EDIT: My question isn't about when and if the finally will execute, it's about whether exceptions still get thrown upwards, but that's been answered now.

Comment: This is pretty close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547791/why-use-finally-in-c

Comment: Which language/platform is this? Java or C#?

Comment: There's a pretty good daily wtf about this:  http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/My-Tales.aspx

Comment: This could also be javascript ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a test class that shows that (1) finally runs, regardless of whether exceptions are thrown; and (2) exceptions are passed along to the caller.

```
public class FinallyTest extends TestCase {
    private boolean finallyWasRun   = false;

    public void testFinallyRunsInNormalCase() throws Exception {
        assertFalse(finallyWasRun);
        f(false);
        assertTrue(finallyWasRun);
    }

    public void testFinallyRunsAndForwardsException() throws Exception {
        assertFalse(finallyWasRun);
        try {
            f(true);
            fail("expected an exception");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            assertTrue(finallyWasRun);
        }
    }

    private void f(boolean withException) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (withException)
                throw new Exception("");
        } finally {
            finallyWasRun = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

The `finally` code will always run, and exceptions will be passed on up, as you say.  That's pretty much the point of `try/finally` - to have some code that will always run, even when exceptions are thrown.

**Edit**: This is true for any language that provides the `try/finally` construct, but there are caveats for some languages, as Adam points out in his comment and Sam points out in his answer.

Comment: this is not really true, see related answers

Comment: I believe that Richie is correct; in a try/finally, the code inside the try block is executed, and regardless of whether an exception is thrown, the code within the finally block is executed afterwards.

Comment: @snake, see my answer and the related answers, there are some edge cases where finally in C# is not going to get executed.

Comment: also what are you answering, C# Java or Javascript?

Comment: There are some edge cases in which the finally block does not run (StackOverflowException in *some* languages, process gets terminated, power cord gets pulled, etc.), but in most cases the finally block will run and then propagate the exception downwards.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is C#, finally will always run unless you get a [StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx) or a [ExecutingEngineException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.executionengineexception.aspx)

Additionally, asynchronous exceptions like ThreadAbortException can interrupt the flow of a finally block causing it to partially execute.

See related questions:

[In C# will the Finally block be executed in a try, catch, finally if an unhandled exception is thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833946/in-c-will-the-finally-block-be-executed-in-a-try-catch-finally-if-an-unhandled)

Answer (score 2):

**If this is C#**:

The answers here are right, the finally is run and the exceptions are "passed up".  But to illustrate how easy it is to figure it out:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("testing");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finally");
        }
    }
}
```

When running this simple, little console application, the exception is thrown and then the finally block is executed.