# no need to use finally in try catch block if catching all exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

If I catch all exceptions;

```
try
{
    ... //code causes error
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   ...//handle all exceptions
}
```

So there is no need to use Finally block? since I catch all exceptions, the program will continue to execute the code after try-catch?

Another  questions is, if use a finally block, how can I catch the errors happened in the final block itself? I mean it looks like we only need to put everything in the try and catch block which is in the very end?

Comment: Yes, but `catch (Exception e)` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: If you want to catch error inside `finally`, you need another `try` - `catch`

Comment: The accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/547806 explains it well.

Answer (score 3):

> So there is no need to use Finally block?

The `finally` clause has very little to do with what, how and how many exceptions you catch. Think of the code that goes in a `finally` clause as clean up code that must be run independently of what happens inside the `try` clause. A typical scenario is the following (I'll use some C#7 for the fun of it):

```
(bool Succesful, object Result) TryDoSomethingDangerous()
{
    var someDisposableObject = new SomeDisposableObject();

    try
    {
        var result = someDisposableObject.DoSomethingDangerous(); //documented to be able to throw SomethingBadHappenedException
        return (true, result);
    }
    catch (SomethingBadHappenedException e)
    {
        Logger.Log(e);
        InformUserSomethingWentWrong(e);
        return (false, null);
    }
    finally
    {
        someDisposableObject.Dispose();
    }
}
```

> since I catch all exceptions, the program will continue to execute the code after try-catch?

This is worrying. Yes if you catch all exceptions your code will keep running (how long is anyone's guess), but this is, in general, a very bad idea. You should only deal with exceptions you know how to fix and recover from. Swallowing exceptions just to keep trudging along is bound to end in disaster.

In general, `catch (System.Exception)` is a bad idea unless you are planning to simply log information and re throw immediately.

> Another questions is, if use a finally block, how can I catch the errors happened in the final block itself? I mean it looks like we only need to put everything in the try and catch block which is in the very end?

Again, you are completely misunderstanding the execution flow in `try-catch-finally`. Code in `finally` is code that *must run* no matter what happens inside the try clause. You seem to believe that it's code that should only run if there is an exception.

In general, its better if code inside a `finally` clause is robust and does not throw exceptions itself. If, given the circumstances, this is not possible then the code inside the `finally` clause will need to have its own exception handling mechanism. In my case I try to avoid this kind of scenario and refactor code accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the OP seems to believe that `finally` is in fact `fault`, which exists in the CLR but isn't exposed in C#.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In situations such as releasing resources, it is used twice instead of writing the same code (both try and catch). Such as closing the database connection and disposing of an object

Comment: Do we need a diagram to say 'finally block is always executed'? :)

Comment: :) i have poor english