# How to launch a template.dot file in edit mode in MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a template.dot Word Document and if I use Windows Explorer, when I right click on it, I can see the functions "**New**, Open, Print, etc", with New being the default option.

If I use Process.Start("template.dot"), this function creates a new document ("document.doc"), because the default choice is "New". 
How can I open the "template.dot" file for editing in MS Word (like when I select the Open function from Right Click)?

Comment: Set ProcessStartInfo.Arguments to "template.dot" while run
Process.Start("winword.exe") and see if that works.

Comment: See: [`ProcessStartInfo.Verb`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Prateek, the command Process.Start("winword.exe") creates a new word document, based on the default action, "New".

Comment: Thanks Jimi, I will check later today and will answe if it's working

Comment: @Nick_F please have a look at the updated post. It's about properly creating and cleaning up objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use interop to start from a .dot/x template like that:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace EditWordDotSO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var applicationWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            applicationWord.Visible = true;

            Document doc = null;

            try
            {
                doc = applicationWord.Documents.Add(@"path\to\your\a.dotx");
                doc.Activate();
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
                //dispose properly as shown below
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You need to add a COM reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` tied to your installed MS Word.

Update: As mentioned by @CindyMeister use

```
this.Application.Documents.Add(@"C:\Test\SampleTemplate.dotx");
```

instead of creating a `new Document()`. Ref: [How to: Programmatically Create New Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhf98b5c.aspx)

PS: The `finally { ... }` block is intended to close the document and dispose the COM objects properly. [Why use finally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547791/why-use-finally-in-c)?

Here is a more involved method to do so inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777422/disposing-of-microsoft-office-interop-word-application) post:

```
finally {
    doc.Close(null, null, null);
    applicationWord.Quit();
    if (doc != null)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
    if (applicationWord != null)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(applicationWord);
    doc = null;
    applicationWord = null;
    GC.Collect(); // final cleanup    
}
```

PPS: It's also possible to add or change the template like that:

```
doc = applicationWord.Documents.Add();
doc.set_AttachedTemplate(@"C:\Test\SampleTemplate.dotx");
doc.UpdateStyles();
```

Comment: Thanks wp78de, it worked! I removed the "finally" part, because I don't know how to use it and I replaced Document dot = new Document() with Document dot = null, because I wanted to open an existent template.

Comment: NEVER EVER use `New Document`in the Word interop. It creates an object in memory that can't be accessed properly and is often orphaned, so that objects remain in memory.

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you, you are right. I was in a rush:  `this.Application.Documents.Add(@"C:\Test\SampleTemplate.dotx");` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhf98b5c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\1.dot") { Verb = "open" });
```

---

Also, full corresponding command can be found in multiple places in the registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\WINWORD.EXE\shell\edit\command

Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Template.8\shell\Open\command
```

The following works for me, but might need the full path in some cases:

```
Process.Start("winword.exe", @"/n C:\1.dot");
```

Comment: Excellent code! This is what I was hoping to obtain. I already implemented the code kindly provided by wp78de, but this code is simpler and it does not need InteropServices. Also, thanks for providing the link to registry commands.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file and choose Open. In Office 2016, a template will open in Edit mode instead of new file mode.

Comment: My question was not related to how to manually open the template, but from inside my own program. Thanks for your answer though.